# What is the meaning/purpose of 一 in the following sentence?

Tags: translation, grammar, verbs

水乌儿一抿翅膀

The waterbird tucked its wings.

Comment: Is this a C-E, or E-C translation? "一抿 "seems a bad choice of word for bird's wings, and does not mean "tucked".

Comment: 抿 means "gently close" close enough to "tuck in"

Comment: The sentence is from Pleco.

Answer (score 2):

[一] + [v] depicts a 'single' movement  (implies starting abruptly or carrying out decisively)

Example:

**挥**利剑砍下敌人头颅 = "**swing** a sharp sword and cut off the enemy's head"

**一挥**利剑，砍下敌人头颅 = "**with one swing** of a sharp sword, cut off the enemy's head" (*you can imagine this movement must be starting abruptly and carried out decisively*)

~

**展翅**飞上天空 - "**spread the wings** and fly up to the sky"

**一展翅**便即飞上天空 - "**once spread the wings**, it started flying up to the sky "

> 水乌儿一抿翅膀

水乌儿**一抿**翅膀，轻轻降落在我的前草坪上 - The waterfowl with **one gentle tuck** of its wings, landed softly on my front lawn